# How can I run two forms simultaneously using threads in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I have created a web service project in C#, and in this service I have two functions one that will perform a search and one that will perform some registration task. In the same solution I have added two windows form application projects, one for the registration and the other for the search procedure; I would like to activate both forms at the same time but I do not know how to do that, I learnt about threads and that they can activate multiple tasks at the same time. I want to use threads to call both forms to be activated and work in parallel.

Comment: What is your definition of Activate? In c# context, Activate means "To focus on form and bring it to front". You can not do that to two forms simultaneously.

Comment: I mean to run the form

Comment: There's no "running" the form. There is one message loop, and the message loop is shared by all windows created on the same thread. If you want two forms to show at the same time, just show them both (`otherForm.Show()`). No multi-threading needed.